# My friends can't interact with things near my house in a Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a Minecraft server that I play with my friends, and I made a house near the spawn area. My friends can normally interact with items like doors, trapdoors, and chests in each others houses. However, they can't interact with items near my house, even though I can. Why is that happening?

We are using DiscordSRV, SkinRestorer (because it's an offline server) and UltimateTimber.

Comment: Is your server modded in any way such as plugins?

Comment: @Topcode yes, it has DiscordSRV, SkinRestorer (bc its an offline server) and UltimateTimber

Comment: Spawn protection maybe ? You might be a OP so you can interact but your friend can't. Check you `spawn-protection` value in `server.properties` file. If it is not 0, set it to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Since your house is near the spawn area, you should check your settings for griefing near spawn, and if it is on, turn it off to [hopefully] remove the problem.